# In TypeScript config file 'tsconfig.json', is it redundant to set 'lib' compiler option to both 'dom' AND 'dom.iterable'?

Tags: typescript

Based on the [TypeScript documentation on the `lib` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib), is it redundant to set `lib` compiler option to both `dom` and `dom.iterable` in TypeScript config file `tsconfig.json`?

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable"],
  }
}
```

I personally find the above setting to be redundant, but I have seen many sample codes/blog posts using the above option. But since I'm not sure, I want to know why the above settings would be used over the following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom"],
  }
}
```

Maybe I'm just being nitpicky... Or maybe there is a valid reason unknown to me why one would specify both `dom` and `dom.iterable`. Any clarifications would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## tl;dr: No, specifying both is not redundant.

`dom.iterable` **adds** definitions for iterables to various DOM APIs. You would include `dom` definitions if you're working with a runtime environment with DOM APIs. And you'd include `dom.iterable` if you are working with a runtime environment that support iterable methods on various DOM APIs. Including `dom` by itself when you're working with a runtime environment that support iterable methods on the DOM APIs that have them will mean you'll get type errors when attempting to access those iterable methods. Including `dom.iterable` by itself won't work as it adds to the `dom` definitions.

## An example of differences

Here's an example of just one difference between the two definitions:

In the `dom` definitions, `FormData` looks like this:

```
interface FormData {
    append(name: string, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void;
    delete(name: string): void;
    get(name: string): FormDataEntryValue | null;
    getAll(name: string): FormDataEntryValue[];
    has(name: string): boolean;
    set(name: string, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: FormDataEntryValue, key: string, parent: FormData) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
}
```

– [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/39ff1568e9676d40cf545477e9fd04077eff9b78/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5406-L5414)

In the `dom.iterable` definitions, `FormData` looks like this:

```
interface FormData {
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[string, FormDataEntryValue]>;
    /**
     * Returns an array of key, value pairs for every entry in the list.
     */
    entries(): IterableIterator<[string, FormDataEntryValue]>;
    /**
     * Returns a list of keys in the list.
     */
    keys(): IterableIterator<string>;
    /**
     * Returns a list of values in the list.
     */
    values(): IterableIterator<FormDataEntryValue>;
}
```

– [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/39ff1568e9676d40cf545477e9fd04077eff9b78/lib/lib.dom.iterable.d.ts#L79-L93)

The definitions don't replace each other but are [merged](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces).

Below are the definition files for your own comparison:

- [`dom`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts)
- [`dom.iterable`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.iterable.d.ts)

## A practical test

Knowing the differences above you can do the following test:

1. Setup a TypeScript project with the following config (the important bit is the empty array config for `lib`, everything else is just the defaults from `tsc --init`):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [],

    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

2. Create an `index.ts` with the following contents:

```
const data = new FormData();
```

You should get an error from TypeScript:

> Cannot find name 'FormData'.

3. Add `"DOM"` to the lib configuration:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM"],

    ...
  }
```

This resolves the error as `FormData` is declared in the definitions for `dom`.

4. Add a call to the `keys` method from `FormData`, your `index.ts` should look like this:

```
const data = new FormData();

data.keys();
```

You should get an error from TypeScript:

> Property 'keys' does not exist on type 'FormData'.

5. Add `"DOM.Iterable"` to the lib configuration:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],

    ...
  }
```

This resolves the error as the definitions for `dom.iterable` declares some iterable methods for `FormData`, `keys` being one of them.

6. Remove `"DOM"` from the lib configuration, leaving just `"DOM.Iterable"`:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM.Iterable"],

    ...
  }
```

You'll get an error again.

Comment: I would like to upvote this answer a thousand times! Best explanation I found. Thanks!